# Calculate overall attribution with Shapley values

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, shapley-value

I'm using a shap KernelExplainer to interprete my model and I'd like to display an indication of why the explainer sorted the features in that order. For example, some kind of overall score that justifies, in a numerical way, why each feature is ranked as it is. To explain myself I attach and example of what I want to achieve. It's the explanation of a dataset made of 5 variables (A-E). The numbers between square brackets would be the overall attribution of each property. What I want to get. Look at the numbers between squared brackets

[image]

As I work with a KernelExplainer, I only get back the shap values for every feature along the test samples. Thus I also wonder if I could calculate the overall score myself and how (mean, std, variance, sum... of the individual shapley value for every feature)?

Thanks for your help.